# Change QTableView's scroll orientation

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4, qtableview

I have been looking around and I can't seem to find any example that would help me change the scroll orientation of the wheel in a `QTableView`. This is my best shot at trying to.

this is what I did to scroll horizontally:

```
def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
    #some of my widgets are disabled, I can simply do another if for enabled ones

    if obj and obj.isEnabled() and event.type() == QEvent.Wheel and self.shift_key:
        newEvent = QWheelEvent(obj.mapToParent(event.pos()), event.globalPos(),
                               event.delta(), event.buttons(),
                               event.modifiers(), 1)
        QApplication.instance().postEvent(obj.parent(), newEvent)
        return True

    if event.type() == QEvent.KeyPress and event.key() == Qt.Key_Shift:
        self.shift_key = True
        return True
    elif event.type() == QEvent.KeyRelease and event.key() == Qt.Key_Shift:
        self.shift_key = False
        return True

    return QObject.eventFilter(self, obj, event)
```

the problem arises when I hover my mouse on the header or a blank space as it does not scroll horizontally and it also displays an error that says

`QApplication::postEvent: Unexpected null receiver`

How do i implement a horizontal scrolling with `scroll` + `shift`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want that when the focus is in the `viewport()` of the `QTableView` pressures `shitf + scroll` the horizontal scrollbar moves a possible solution is to overwrite the `wheelEvent` method, make a filter and send the event to `horizontalScrollBar()`:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

class TableView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def wheelEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == QtCore.Qt.ShiftModifier:
            QtGui.QApplication.sendEvent(self.horizontalScrollBar(), event)
        else:
            QtGui.QTableView.wheelEvent(self, event)

class Widget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        tableview = TableView()
        lay.addWidget(tableview)

        model = QtGui.QStandardItemModel(10, 10)
        tableview.setModel(model)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: What if the widgets inside the table is disabled?

Comment: @JuanCarlosAsuncion you could explain yourself better, and provide a [mcve] like the one I show, what widget?

Comment: yes, sorry I am till making an example as posting my code would be too large for an example

Comment: @JuanCarlosAsuncion 
Okay, I'll wait for you to post a decent [mcve], I said it for the other question that you delayed, I do not know how long. :)

Comment: I'll mark this as answered now as I really think this calls for another question as the event ignores disabled widgets. thanks for the boost, I'll try to solve my other problems the best I can. this is the problem that really bugged me